# show and hide divs based on radio button click

Tags: jquery, show-hide

My html and jquery code here. This is a very simple test but it still can't work..

**Here is html:**

```
  <p>Select a question to see the answer.</p>
  <div id="questionArea" class="questionArea" >
    Question 1 <input type="radio" id="question1" class="question" name="radioGroup1" />
    Question 2 <input type="radio" id="question2" class="question" name="radioGroup1" />
    Question 3 <input type="radio" id="question3" class="question" name="radioGroup1" />
  </div>

  <div id="answerArea" class="answerArea">
    <div id="answer1" class="answer">First Answer</div>
    <div id="answer2" class="answer">Second Answer</div>
    <div id="answer3" class="answer">Third Answer</div>
  </div>
```

**Here is jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".answerArea").hide();
  $("input[$name='radioGroup1']").click(function() {
            var answer = $(this).val();
            $(".answerArea").hide();
            $("#" + answer).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is another way to show/hide, although it isn't a good approach, but I just want to know why it can't work..

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

            $("div.answerArea").hide();

                $('#question1').click(function () {
                    $('#answer2').hide('fast');
                    $('#answer3').hide('fast');
                    $('#answer1').show('fast');

                });

                $('#question2').click(function () {

                      $('#answer1').hide('fast');
                      $('#answer3').hide('fast');
                      $('#answer2').show('fast');

                 });

                   $('#question3').click(function () {

                      $('#answer1').hide('fast');
                      $('#answer2').hide('fast');
                      $('#answer3').show('fast');

                 });


    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".answerArea").hide();` hides the parent element that contains the answers. You can't show a child if the parent is hidden.

I'd use the index of the children to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".answer").hide();

    $(".question").click(function() {
        $(".answer").hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
});
```

This will hide all of the answer elements and then show the one corresponding to the question.

Comment: Good answer...I just wanted to add that if the user refreshes the page after already having a radio button selected, the only way for them to see the answer again would be to click a different radio button. Two ways to solve this: (1): Reset the form when the page loads (`$('#myForm')[0].reset()`)  (2): Trigger the click event when the page first loads, e.g. `$(".question").click(function() ... ).trigger('click');`

Comment: @Blender It did hide all the answer elements, but still can't show up when clicked.. And can I ask, what's the "eq" and index() means? Thanks.

Comment: change `$(".answerArea").hide();` to `$(".answer").hide();`?

Comment: @Zac Oh,yh..It finally shows up.. Thank you a lot.. It's weird. I can't understand why..

Comment: Blender explains why, just forgot to change it in his code. Hopefully he will edit it when he sees this.

Comment: @Sunny: `.eq(n)` selects the `n`th element. It's what you should be doing instead of `$(elements[n])`. `.index()` gets the index of the element in the selector.